# Localize string properties inside angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Inside my angularjs controller I'm injecting translation service

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', translationService) {

    //Run translation if selected language changes
    $scope.translate = function () {            
        translationService.getTranslation($scope, $scope.selectedLanguage);
    };       
    $scope.translate();
}
```

and inside view I'm translating text like

```
{{ translation.HelloWorld }}
```

where HelloWorld is a string inside language json file.

Since I am able to detect currently selected language using `$scope.selectedLanguage` which will return string of selected language `eng`, `rus`, `fra` how can I translate text injected inside object property inside controller, for example

```
var myObj = { Id: 1, Name: "Default", Description: "Default" };
```

How can I localize Name and Description property?

Update:

```
app.service('translationService', function ($resource) {    
    this.getTranslation = function ($scope, language) {
        var languageFilePath = '../app/locStrings/translation_' + language + '.json';
        $resource(languageFilePath).get(function (data) {
            $scope.translation = data;
        });
    };
});
```

where each file has prefix `translation_` like

```
translation_eng.json
```

or  `translation_fra.json` 
with content

```
{
    "HELLO_WORLD": "Hello world en",
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How can I use localization in Angular?**

You can use localization in angular by simply using a rootScope object. It works very much similar to .net localization concept.

> **Localization Schema.**

It is quite similar to .net localization, in .net you can put one localization file in which all language translations are stored in tabular format.
Here you can use Two files or One file as per your convenience. *(I prefer separate file for each language)*

**All languages in one file.**

```
{
  translationkey1:{
      en:'translationValue_english1',
      hi:'translationValue_hindi1',
      fr:'translationValue_french1',
  },
  translationkey2:{
      en:'translationValue_english2',
      hi:'translationValue_hindi2',
      fr:'translationValue_french2',
  },
  translationkey3:{
      en:'translationValue_english2',
      hi:'translationValue_hindi2',
      fr:'translationValue_french2',
  }
}
```

**Separate file for each language.**

```
{
  translationkey1:'translationValue1',
  translationkey2:'translationValue2',
  translationkey3:'translationValue3',
}
```

> **Usage in View**

Copy translation file object in translations object of rootscope so you can access it everywhere.

**All languages in one file.**

```
{{translations[myObj.Name][selectedLanguage]}} // It will return English value for specific value from translation object.
```

**Separate file for each language.**

If you are using separate files, then no need to store selectedLanguage format, just keep translation object as per language.

```
{{translations[myObj.Name]}}
```

> **Which is good approach.**

Using separate file for each language is good approach if translation files is too big. It increases server hits but you can maintain translations easily.

Using single file to store all languages is quite increases memory consumption. But reduces server hits.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KqXe2u5aUVuQBShkvcgN?p=preview) is your answer.

Comment: I'm assigning this myObj.Name to the $scope.myName inside controller,  which is binded to the view. How can I translate this property in this case? or how would you do this?

Comment: I think you are using first method. You are putting all translations in one file only. Just hold translations object in $rootScope.translations, then you can use {{ translations[myName][selectedLanguage] }}